# Facing issues in CommandLine namespace in Visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am using visual studio 2017 and `.net` framework 4.1 is installed. And I also installed command line parser `V2.1beta` version using `nuGet`. 
But when I using namespace "using CommandLine; IT is throwing below error:

> "Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'CommandLine' could not be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   ReadText.Demo   E:\IKNIT\commandline-master\demo\ReadText.Demo\Options.cs   1   Active
>   "

What could be the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Please learn how to format your questions, this is very unreadable.

Comment: Also include the code causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be that .NET Framework 4.1 is not compatible with .NET Standard 1.5.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

That would be problematic because the command line parser depends on .NET Standard 1.5.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommandLineParser/2.1.1-beta